# List index out of range: Hello Python

Tags: python

Hello i'm new to Python and i'm having a little trouble. I'm reading Hello Python
and i'm typing a code down it told me to type, but when i run the code, it gives me an error.

Error: caves[next_cave].append(i) List index out of range

This is the code i'm typing out.

Code:

```
from random import choice

cave_numbers = range(0,20)
caves =  []
for i in cave_numbers:
    caves.append([])

    unvisited_caves = range(0,20)
    visited_caves = [0]
    unvisited_caves.remove(0)

    while unvisited_caves != []:
        i = choice(visited_caves)
        if len(caves[i]) >= 3:
            continue        
        next_cave = choice(unvisited_caves)
        caves[i].append(next_cave)
        caves[next_cave].append(i)

        visited_caves.append(next_cave)
        unvisited_caves.remove(next_cave)

        for number in cave_numbers:
            print number, ":", caves[number]
        print'-----------'

    for i in cave_numbers:
        while len(caves[i]) < 3:
            passage_to = choice(cave_numbers)
            cave[i].append(passage_to)

        for number in cave_numbers:
            print number, ":", caves[number]
        print '----------'
```

Thank you for answering my question

-Cyr

Comment: Are you sure you got your indentation right?

Comment: Everything after `caves.append([])` needs to be outdented, otherwise it's all inside `for i in cave_numbers`

Comment: *Thank you for answering my question* - but ... you haven't asked a question. "What's wrong?" "What does the error mean?" "How could I debug this myself?" "What's a List index?" ...

Comment: To be fair to the OP, the question is prefaced with "I am new to Python" and "I'm reading Hello Python and i'm typing a code down it told me to type". Upon locating the text "Hello Python" and the code referenced by the OP, indeed the issue is simply indentation (something I also stumbled with at first becoming aware of while learning python). Although critique of the code logic is great, it's probably not addressing the goal of the OP and the question which is simply to get the code behavior to reflect that of the exercises explained in the textbook. I digress, carry on! :)

Answer (score 3):

`choice(unvisited_caves)` in going to return a number from `unvisited_caves = range(0,20)`, so that would be a random number from 0..19.

`caves[next_cave].append(i)` will error 90% of the time (18/20 times) because all you have done is `caves =  []` and `caves.append([])`, so `caves` has at most one element in the first iteration of your program.

Maybe you have an indentation problem, but overall, using random numbers of a different range to index a list seems like a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is just with indentation. I believe that your intent was to use the for loop to give your list of caves 20 empty arrays before you begin your simulation. As you had it, your loop would add one array and then start the simulation right away. Your caves list is not ready for this, and so it errors.

The following should work better:

```
from random import choice

cave_numbers = range(0,20)
caves =  []
for i in cave_numbers:
    caves.append([])

unvisited_caves = range(0,20)
visited_caves = [0]
unvisited_caves.remove(0)

while unvisited_caves != []:
    i = choice(visited_caves)
    if len(caves[i]) >= 3:
        continue        
    next_cave = choice(unvisited_caves)
    caves[i].append(next_cave)
    caves[next_cave].append(i)

    visited_caves.append(next_cave)
    unvisited_caves.remove(next_cave)

    for number in cave_numbers:
        print number, ":", caves[number]
    print'-----------'

for i in cave_numbers:
    while len(caves[i]) < 3:
        passage_to = choice(cave_numbers)
        caves[i].append(passage_to)

    for number in cave_numbers:
        print number, ":", caves[number]
        print '----------'
```

I only made two edits:

- First, I unindented so that the while loop comes after the for loop finishes
- You also had a typo where you said `cave[i]` instead of `caves[i]`

Also note, there are some opportunities to simplify your code here. At first this may seem merely aesthetic, but it can actually help avoid errors like this. For example:

```
for i in cave_numbers:
    caves.append([])
```

can become `caves =  [ [] for each in cave_numbers]` which would have left less room for errors.

Comment: To the suggested edit for using `list(range(0,20))`, that's probably a good idea to keep compatible with python 3.x. I use python 2.x, and `range` actually returns a list, and `xrange` returns a range object. In python 3.x however, we must convert to a list to use the `remove` method. Thanks.

Comment: Since the author of the question was getting to the index error though, it is safe to assume he is using python 2.x as well or he wouldn't have made it past the error from 'remove is not defined', and so I voted not to update it.

Answer (score -1):

That error means that at some point, the value in `next_cave` exceeds the length of the `caves` list.

You'd get that same error by doing this:

```
caves = [[0,1,2], [4,5,6]]
caves[2].append([7,8,9])
```